# gcc __attribute__, what does it do?

Tags: gcc

I read a code there is something like this:

```
#define __printf__(a,b) __attribute__((format(printf,a,b,)))
```

In order to under stand `__printf__`, I need to understand what does attibute do,

Could anybody help me understand this?>

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

> format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)
>
> The format attribute specifies that a function takes printf, scanf, strftime or strfmon style arguments which should be type-checked against a format string. For example, the declaration:
>
> ```
>          extern int
>          my_printf (void *my_object, const char *my_format, ...)
>                __attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)));
> ```
>
> causes the compiler to check the arguments in calls to my_printf for consistency with the printf style format string argument my_format.

It's basically a note to the compiler to validate any strings it can at compile time against a given format type.  In the quoted line, it's telling the compiler to validate printf format strings against printf format strings (for example if an int is passed for a `%s` parameter, the compiler should tell the user).

Search for format in the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) for more.